# Loop Swift keeps crashing app

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I am attempting to use a repeat-while loop in Swift. I am trying to use it to grab the items within an array and add it to a variable.

```
var finalEquation = ""
var arrayPoint = 0

        repeat {
            arrayPoint += 1
            finalEquation = finalEquation + String(equation[arrayPoint])
        } while (arrayPoint < equation.count)
```

So I have a variable called "arrayPoint", this increments by 1 each time the loop runs. So the problem I'm having I'm having is with the line:

```
finalEquation = finalEquation + String(equation[arrayPoint])
```

This line takes the item in the array, which is equal to *arrayPoint* and adds it that array item to a variable.

When ever I build and run the code, it compiles without any errors and does not stop me. Then whenever the loop gets activated, the application freezes, and in the output window, I get something saying.

```
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

Then on that line of code that I mentioned earlier, it says: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: May I ask why you're using a `repeat while` loop in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you might run this loop in UI thread which is wrong. 
2nd you are increment the variable before fetch the value. Please move arrayPoint+=1 just after finalEquation line.

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning Swift, but by UI thread, do you mean that it's not within a function, because it is.

Comment: You have already vote down, and then questioning. Vote down means I am wrong and not in context.

Comment: How do you determine that it is wrong to run this code on UI thread?

Comment: because ui is freezing.

Comment: @JavaGeek I never voted down, in fact what you said worked perfectly.

Comment: Dannymout when you run a long task it must not be in UI thread. If it is in UI it freez the ui.

Comment: If so, please select my answer as answer. Thanks

Comment: @JavaGeek I did select is as answer, I was just wondering what UI thread means.

Comment: Please go to the apple developer website and check the UI thread. At the moment I am unable to open the developer website. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Putting the incrementing before your usage of the `arrayPoint` makes the range [1, count], but the array only has indices [0, count - 1].

You should move the increment to be the last thing in the `repeat` block.

```
var finalEquation = ""
var arrayPoint = 0

repeat {
    finalEquation = finalEquation + String(equation[arrayPoint])
    arrayPoint += 1
} while (arrayPoint < equation.count)
```

On a side note, `arrayIndex` would be a more appropriate name. The number used to reference an element in an array is called an "index".

Also, you should read about breakpoints, so that you can better debug off-by-one errors like this yourself.